# Overlapping mouseareas in QtQuick 2.0

Tags: qt, qml

I have list of items in QML 2.0 and I want to display item's context menu (red box in the picture) only when mouse is inside black mouseArea. Context menu contains a few buttons, each of them has own museArea. In QtQuick 1.0 it works as expected, but in 2.0 not. When I move the cursor between small red boxed (context menu's items), black MouseArea::onExited is called (and context menu isn't shown). It looks like small red mouseareas covered the larger, black mousearea. If I set:

```
z: 10
```

in black mouseArea, onExited isn't called when cursor is above small red boxes, but I can't use small mouseares hovering effects. What should I do to have an access to small red boxes' mouseareas and simultanously not calling black mouseArea::onExited when cursor is above red box?

[image: QtQuick 2.0 MouseAreas]

Comment: You should add as short as possible (still complete and valid) QML code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on the mouseArea *onExited* and *onEntered* events, you could enable hovering and check the *containsMouse* property. Here's a working example (QtQuick 2.0):

```
Column
{
    spacing: 10
    Repeater
    {
        model:4
        Rectangle
        {
            height: 100
            width: parent.width
            border.color: "black"

            MouseArea
            {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
            }

            Rectangle
            {
                visible: mouseArea.containsMouse
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.margins: 20
                width: 200
                border.color: "red"

                Rectangle
                {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    color: "purple"
                    width: 20
                    height: 20
                    MouseArea
                    {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onClicked: print("clicked")
                    }
                }
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If a `MouseArea` overlaps with the area of other `MouseArea` items,
>   you can choose to propagate `clicked`, `doubleClicked` and
>   `pressAndHold` events to these other items by setting
>   p`ropagateComposedEvents` to `true` and rejecting events that should
>   be propagated. See the [propagateComposedEvents](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.2/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop) documentation for
>   details.

[Source](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.2/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#details)